# enable HDMI port after Disable it with shell programing in raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi3, hdmi

I used a raspberry pi 3 model b v1.2. raspberry connected to a TV with HDMI port. I want to disable and enable HDMI port with shell program. I use [this code](https://gist.github.com/AGWA/9874925) for doing that. also, i install a teamviewer in raspberry and can control that with my laptop. when i run `sh rpi-hdmi.sh off` in terminal, HDMI port disable correctly and see this message in terminal:

```
Power off HDMI
```

but when i run `sh rpi-hdmi.sh on`, i see in TV that clear "no signal" message. but it not showing anything and i see just black tv.
when i run `sh rpi-hdmi.sh on` for first one, i see this message:

```
Power on HDMI with preferred settings
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

but for second one, i see just this message:

```
Power on HDMI with preferred settings
```

What must i do, for showing desktop in TV after enable HDMI port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run sh `rpi-hdmi.sh on`, the line of `tvservice -p` need some time to run correctly. if you want to enable HDMI port quickly, you may run this code:

```
tvservice -p
xset dpms force on
```